# Reallocate partition space from /boot to /

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, hard-drive

This is how my harddisk is partitioned currently.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       386G  361G  5.9G  99% /
none            4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.0G  4.1k  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           401M  1.5M  400M   1% /run
none            5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
none            2.1G  160k  2.1G   1% /run/shm
none            105M   74k  105M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1        51G  330M   48G   1% /boot
```

Here is my fdisk data

```
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    99999743    49998848   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       100001790   875999231   387998721    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda3   *   876008385   976768064    50379840    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       100001792   110000127     4999168   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       110002176   875999231   382998528   83  Linux
```

As you can see 51GB is used as /boot which I think a wastage. So I'm thinking of reallocating some space from /boot to /.

Is there a any way I can do it ?

If there is how much space I sholud left for /boot?

Comment: Would help if you could include the partitioning table details (output of fdisk print option).  In any event you might be in for a little work.

Comment: @mdpc I updated the question with fdisk data. Can you please chek it and tell what I can do here.

Comment: Since the partitions are not next to each other on the disk, your best bet is to backup everything, format the drive, and restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning** This will take some time, so start this before going to bed. ;)

**Warning** If there is a power failure during this operation you *will* loose all of your data, so do a full system backup before starting.

1. Download, burn and boot the [gparted live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)
2. Shrink `/dev/sda5` to 1GByte
3. Move `/dev/sda6` to the left next to `/dev/sda5`
4. Extend `/dev/sda6` to the end of the hard drive
5. Apply changes
6. Go to bed.

Comment: Will this work fine if there was no powe failure?

Comment: Well, yes, unless there was a lightning strike, an earthquake, a brownout, a redout, a cosmic ray, a buffer overrun, a kernel panic, a ...
**Back up your data first!**

Comment: Well I'm going to need some backup drives ready the.. Thanks for the help. :)